# GNU Linux kernel architecture

Tags: kernel

Does the GNU Linux kernel downloadable from www.kernel.org comes with all the hardware architecture like arm, amd, ppc etc?

In the arch folder, I couldnt find any architecture like amd64 ( the 64 bit intel architecture ) or is it referred as something else.

Where can I see the list of architecture supported by the kernel and their corresponding abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a single kernel tree containing all the code for all the architectures it supports. The list of architectures supported by the Linux kernel (which isn’t a GNU project) is given by the list of directories in [`arch`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch). Currently:

- alpha: Alpha
- arc: ARC
- arm: 32-bit ARM
- arm64: 64-bit ARM (Aarch64)
- avr32: 32-bit AVR
- blackfin: Blackfin
- c6x: C6x
- cris: ETRAX CRIS
- frv: Fujitsu FR-V
- h8300: Hitachi H8
- hexagon: Qualcomm Hexagon
- ia64: 64-bit Itanium
- m32r: Renesas M32R
- m68k: Motorola 68000
- metag: Meta FPGAs
- microblaze: Xilinx MicroBlaze
- mips: various MIPS
- mn10300: Panasonic MN10300
- nios2: Altera Nios II
- openrisc: OpenRISC (also known as or1k)
- parisc: PA/RISC
- powerpc: 32- and 64-bit PowerPC
- s390: IBM S/390 (64-bit only nowadays)
- score: SunplusCT S+CORE
- sh: Hitachi SuperH
- sparc: 32- and 64-bit SPARC
- tile: Tilera
- um: user-mode Linux
- unicore32: UniCore-32
- x86: 32- and 64-bit x86 (the latter also known as amd64)
- xtensa: Tensilica Xtensa

You’ll note that most 32-/64-bit variants have been merged into single `arch` directories.

Comment: so, the x86 has both 32 and 64, but the arm is divided into arm and arm64. Any specific reason? It only creates a confusion which led me looking for amd64 aka x86_64 directory.

Comment: ARM has a ton of [machine-specific setup](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm) whereas Aarch64 is much more unified; merging the two would just make a mess of Aarch64 without actually bringing much benefit. All the other 32-/64-bit merged architectures are much cleaner than ARM.

Comment: OKay, thanks. so the linux kernel comprises of the source code of all the architecutre it supports and everything is downloaded irrespective of which architecture you are using? I mean, there is nothing called linux kernel arm download or linux kernel ppc download. Everything is in one tar ball?

Comment: That's right, everything is in one tarball. I think most people working with the kernel clone the repository, but the same applies. Some devices have more-or-less proprietary forks of the kernel, but that's rather irrelevant here (since most people don't have access to the source code).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Kconfig` files in the `arch/` subdirectories. If you look in `x86` at `Kconfig.cpu`, you will see lots of entries that depend on `X86_64`. These all deal with Intel 64bit variants. If you really mean "AMD", there are some more quirks that deal with AMD in `Kconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the GNU Linux kernel downloadable from www.kernel.org comes with all the hardware architecture like arm, amd, ppc etc?

Yes. Though regarding ARM, there are numerous systems-on-a-chip, and mainline kernel support for them varies.

> In the arch folder, I couldnt find any architecture like amd64 ( the 64 bit intel architecture ) or is it referred as something else.

It used to be there, but the 32-bit `i386` and 64-bit `amd64` architectures were [unified](https://lwn.net/Articles/246507/) in a single `x86` architecture around 2007. (Linux 2.6.24 from January 2008 already has the unified arch.)